# Automation on MacOS to move PDF files to a specific folder

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I'm looking for a script to look at a folder and find the `PDF` that contains a suffix in the filename and move all of the relatives' PDF to a folder with the same suffix.

e.g., move `PDF` with filename `nameName_USEN_nameName.pdf`

to folder `USEN`

Move `PDF` with filename `nameName_GBEN_nameName.pdf`

to folder `GBEN`

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the `find` *command* in **Terminal**:

```
find /path/to/search -type f -iname '*_USEN_*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv -n {} /path/to/USEN/
```

Then:

```
find /path/to/search -type f -iname '*_GBEN_*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv -n {} /path/to/GBEN/
```

You can also use `.` in place of `/path/to/search` if you want to start the search in the *current directory*.

Also, if there are any *spaces* in the `/path/to/search`, `/path/to/USEN/`, or `/path/to/GBEN/`, either quote the *pathname* or escape the *spaces* with a *backslash* `\`, but not both.

---

If you want to use **Automator**, then here's a screenshot of an example *workflow*:

- Note the **Options** in the second **Find Finder Items** *action*, the **[√] Ignore this actions input** is checked and it's not connected to the **Move Finder Items** *action* above it because of this *option*.

[image: Automator workflow]